# Hyperbolic Solids in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry, 3d-printing, mathematics

How can I construct hyperbolic solids (hyperbolic cube, tetrahedron, etc.) in Blender?

Below is a picture of a hyperbolic cube:

[image]

[Here](http://euler.slu.edu/escher/index.php/Hyperbolic_Geometry) is some more information on hyperbolic solids.

Just to be clear, I would ultimately like to construct a hyperbolic dodecahedron, but I want to learn how to use a general method.

**EDIT:** The solution does not have to be mathematically perfect, but it would be nice. I am trying to 3D print a gift for someone.

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? Or does it just need to look good enough for visualization purposes?

Comment: @Fweeb, good catch. I am trying to make a gift for a math-oriented friend. The mathematical quality does not have to be perfect (though it would be nice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just in it for the looks, the easiest thing would be to take advantage of proportional editing. Using your cube as an example, do the following steps:

1. Sub-divide the cube multiple (Edit mode > Select All [<kbd>A</kbd>] > Specials [<kbd>W</kbd>] > Subdivide... then use the Last Operator panel [<kbd>F6</kbd>] to increase the number of subdivisions to taste).
2. Select just the eight corner vertices on the cube.
3. Enable proportional editing (<kbd>O</kbd>).
4. Change the proportional fall-off to Sharp (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> 3 times if you're at the default of Smooth. Alternatively, there's a drop-down menu in the 3D View's header where you can choose the fall-off using your mouse).
5. Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) those vertices. As you do, scroll your mouse wheel to adjust the fall-off influence of the proportional edit area.
6. To get sharp edges, select all the edges around the model and then crease them with (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) and drag until the value in the header is at `1.0` or just press 1 on your keyboard.

Finally, you may want to also use the Subdivision Surface modifier and the Edge Split modifier to help smooth things out a bit.

[image]